# Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: 'test'

Tags: angular

I want to send a string from the child component to the parent component, the value is substituted but it warns in the console.

Parent TS:

```
export class UserInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  topMadrak='';
 }
```

Parent HTML

```
<div>
...
<p>{{topMadrak}}</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
     <app-edu-degree (strTopMadrak)="topMadrak=$event"></app-edu-degree>
</div>
```

Child TS:

```
export class EduDegreeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.strTopMadrak.emit("test");
  }
  @Output() strTopMadrak = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Console:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: 'test'.
```

**How do I fix this problem?**

Answer (score 2):

you can use `changeDetectorRef` in your parent component in your life cycle `ngAfterContentChecked`.

If I'm taking your example:

```
export class UserInfoComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
  topMadrak='';
 }
```